# filezilla get closed automatically when I clicked on any folder on server side

Tags: filezilla

I have installed ubuntu 16.04, but filezila is not working in my pc.

When I connect then connection is successful but when I clicked on any folder on server side then filezila get closed.

Filezilla version : 3.21, 3.20

Comment: You can check Filezilla's log files for any disconnection-related messages or errors. If you find anything relevant there, add more details to the question so it becomes answerable.

Answer (score 1):

Download Filezilla 3.27.1, it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the queue pane under. Make sure that "Action after queue completion" - "Close FileZilla" is not selected.